# Loading map data from highcharts.com

Tags: highcharts

I am playing with Highmaps to see how it works. I notice that in its examples, all the maps are loaded from this place:

```
https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/
```

Questions:

1. Is the above link for production?
2. Would it be better to have a copy on my own server? If yes, where to download all the maps?

Comment: This is actually the official map collection. You can download whatever map you want from there and have a copy of your own (with respect to copyrights), and you can load them directly from the collection itself (in the docs they show how to do that). http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/map-collection

Comment: MorKadosh, thanks for chiming in! Is https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/ for production use? I need to use the maps for the world, all countries, and US' counties. For example: https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/mm/mm-all.js. Can I just use the maps this way? I would like to make sure this link is for production.

Comment: Yes it is. BUT In my projects, I rather have a local copy of it...

Comment: It would be hard to download them all. Anywhere to down them all in a zip? Why do you want to have a local copy if the link I mentioned above is production ready? Best.

Comment: I just want them close :) but anyway, I don't know if there's a compressed version of all maps

Comment: Morkadosh, thank for helping me out. If you could summarize our chat in an answer, I will select it. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed. 
The mapdata is actually the official collection of maps by Highcharts.

As described on the official docs: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/map-collection

You can simply load the maps using `script` tags, AMD or any other way of module loading, by including the files hosted on Highcharts's servers, for instance:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>
```

All of the maps in the collection are also available in geojson format and svg.

In my projects, I'd rather download the maps and load them from my server's local system.
I don't believe it really matters, but since I did not expect these maps to change any soon, I could allow myself to have a copy of my own.
The reason I did it was since I used AMD (requirejs), and with that I could load the maps as modules.